# Pandas: Merging rows with the same index, while creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I just started using Pandas and have a dataframe containing multiple rows with the same indexing, indicating a variable has certain features, e.g.

```
ItemID       Property    Numerical_value
A1           'Red'       10     
A1           'Fruit'     0
B1           'Red'       25
C1           'Liquid'    0
```

The assumptions holding for my data are; 
Only rows where the property is 'Red' have a numerical value. And
if an item has the property 'Fruit' it also has the property Red.

The issue I'm facing is transforming this dateframe to follow a one-hot encoding scheme for each of the itemID's while also saving the numerical value if it's present, e.g.;

```
ItemID       Red&Fruit   Just_red  Other  Numerical_value
A1           1           0         0      10         
B1           0           1         0      25
C1           0           0         1      0
```

Currently, I have written the following code;

```
def read_report:
    fp = 'file_path'
    df = (pd.read_csv(fp))
    group = df.groupby('ItemID')['Property','Numerical_value'].apply(test_function)
```

with

```
def test_function(df):
    if 'Fruit' in df.values:
       num_val = df[df['Property'] == 'Red']['Numerical_value'].values[0]
       return pd.Series({'Red&Fruit': '1', 'Num_val': num_val})
    elif 'Red' in df.values:
       num_val= df[df['Property'] == 'Red']['Num_val'].values[0]
       return pd.Series({'Just_red': '1', 'Num_val': num_val})
    else:
       return pd.Series({'Other': '1', 'Num_val': 0})
```

This does not seem to be optimal, especially the way to get the numerical value for each summarized row feels rather hacky.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me: in group 1 you have an item 'Red' and one item 'Fruit', which is 'Red & Fruit' according to what you are saying. Are these two different objects? Or any time there is a 'Fruit' there will also be a 'Red'?

Comment: Your last statement is correct, it is the same object. If we encounter the property 'Fruit' we are sure it also has the property 'Red'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend getting the set of properties by group:

```
df.groupby('ItemID')['Property'].apply(set)
Out[15]: 
ItemID
A1    {'Red', 'Fruit'}
B1             {'Red'}
C1          {'Liquid'}
```

You could then use `get_dummies`:

```
 df.groupby('ItemID')['Property'].apply(set).str.get_dummies()
Out[17]: 
        {"'Liquid'"}  {"'Red'", "'Fruit'"}  {"'Red'"}
ItemID                                               
A1                 0                     1          0
B1                 0                     0          1
C1                 1                     0          0
```

In your example you just need to rename the columns. However, you would probably want to `replace` the values after the `groupby` operation.

Finally, merge with numerical values:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('ItemID')['Property'].apply(set).str.get_dummies(),
           df.groupby('ItemID')['Numerical_value'].first()], axis=1)
Out[21]: 
        {"'Liquid'"}  {"'Red'", "'Fruit'"}  {"'Red'"}  Numerical_value
ItemID                                                                
A1                 0                     1          0               10
B1                 0                     0          1               25
C1                 1                     0          0                0
```

Here I take the first numeric value, as in your example.